# TypeError: frame_apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'broadcast'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-maps-api-3

I am running a function on every row of a Pandas dataset using .loc.

```
dm.loc[:50, 'address_components'] = dm.loc[:50, ['description', 'city']].apply(lambda row: get_address(row[0], row[1]), axis=1)
```

The function itself is below, although the error doesn't apply to the function I'm passing

```
def get_address(address, city):
    geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key=api_key, domain='maps.googleapis.com', scheme=None, client_id=None, 
                      secret_key=None, 
                     user_agent=None)
    geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=0.0, swallow_exceptions=True, return_value_on_exception=None)
    # cleanup address
    address = address.strip(' ').strip(',')
    full_addr = '{}, {}'.format(address, city)
    #print(full_addr)
    data = geocode(full_addr, timeout=None, exactly_one=True)
    if data:
        #print(data.raw)
        return data.raw

    return None
```

and the response

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-46aa2724c2f6> in <module>
      1 
      2 
----> 3 dm.loc[:50, 'address_components'] = dm.loc[:50, ['description', 'city']].apply(lambda row: get_address(row[0], row[1]), axis=1)

~/virt_env/virt2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6909             result_type=result_type,
   6910             args=args,
-> 6911             kwds=kwds,
   6912         )
   6913         return op.get_result()

TypeError: frame_apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'broadcast'
```

That error is new as the function did run before without issues, and started throwing an error message only after I updated Pandas to 1.0.4. However, it persists even after I downgraded pandas back to 0.25.1. Broadcast parameter also doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: got the same error few days back after update, must be some bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it really is a version issue. Downgraded back to pandas 0.25, restarted the kernel and it's flying again!

Comment: For me, restarting the kernel fixed the problem.  (Pandas 1.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but you seem to be assigning to the first 50 rows each time apply iterates, whilst iterating each row

```
dm.loc[:50, 'address_components'] =
```

should be

```
dm["address_components"] = dm.loc[:50, ['description', 'city']].apply(lambda row: get_address(row[0], row[1]), axis=1)
```